# CodeIgniter core/URI.php script_name empty needle warning

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm getting warning in my CodeIgniter Application.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: strpos(): Empty needle
<!-- <p>Filename: core/URI.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 191</p> -->
<p>Line Number: 187</p> -->
```

My apache conf settings look like

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|fonts|assets|uploads|images)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The code at CodeIgniter core/URI.php looks like

```
private function _detect_uri()
        {
            if ( ! isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) OR ! isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']))
            {
                    return '';
            }

            $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
          187 -> if (strpos($uri, $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) === 0)
            {
                    $uri = substr($uri, strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
            }
            elseif (strpos($uri, dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) === 0)
            {
                    $uri = substr($uri, strlen(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])));
            }
...}
```

It is obvious that SCRIPT_NAME is empty. However, why it is getting into line 187? isset() function would have returned right above. Isn't it?

I saw some answer that my Rewrite Conf might be the problem. However, I do not see anything wrong with it.

Please help me solve it out.

Thanks.

Happy New Year.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your rewrite rules in an `.htaccess` file rather than the `VirtualHost` section of your site conf file. `isset()` will still return TRUE for something set to an empty string. Either that or modify the core file to check if `SCRIPT_NAME` is set OR an empty string on line 181.

Apparently, this has something to do with an age old bug that is either [Apache's](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40102) fault or [PHP's](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38141), but neither seems to accept responsibility. Putting your rewrite in an `.htaccess` file will properly set the `SCRIPT_NAME` to index.php.